# How to use Scanner and conditions in Java?

Tags: java, input

I'm fairly new to java and now I'm testing the `Scanner`! Here is my code:

```
package Examples;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserLogin
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name!");
        String keyboard= in.nextLine();    

        System.out.println("Welcome: " + keyboard);
        System.out.println("What is your password?");

        Scanner x= new Scanner (System.in);
        int password= x.nextInt();


        if(password ==14567) 
        {
            System.out.println("Password accepted ! you are welcome!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry wrong password! Try again");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int password2=input.nextInt();
            while (password2==password);
            {
                System.out.println("Welcome!!!!");
            }   
        }
    }   
}
```

I want the user's name, password and that is it! But I noticed that when I ask the name even if I press the enter key, it will ask me the password right away. So I want to make sure I get a name.  Also when I ask the password I want to be able to give him few chances before saying goodbye.

```
Please enter your name!
michel
Welcome: michel
What is your password?
12345
Sorry wrong password! Try again
12345
```

This is what I get on the console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First things first, You have declared unnecessary `scanner` objects. You only need to make `scanner` object once. You can take input using that object as many times as you want.

Second thing is you need to remove semi-colon you have put at the end of `while (password2==password);`because putting a `semi-colon` there will execute the block of while loop regardless of whether condition of while loop is true of false.

Now to do what you want, try following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner in= new Scanner (System.in);
 int default_password = 14567;
 int counter = 3;

System.out.println("Please enter your name!");
String keyboard= in.nextLine();    

System.out.println("Welcome: " + keyboard);
System.out.println("What is your password?");

int password= in.nextInt();

if(password == default_password) 
{
    System.out.println("Password accepted ! you are welcome!");

}
else
{
    while(counter > 0)
    {
      System.out.println("Sorry wrong password! Try again");

       password = in.nextInt();

       if (password == default_password)
       {
         System.out.println("Welcome!!!!");
         break;
       }
       else
       {
        counter--;
       }  


    }
    if(counter== 0)
           System.out.println("Good Bye !!");
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me amazingnick200.Tyhe It run but the counter does not work, i mean i could put a zillion time a bad password without saying goodbye!

Comment: You mean you want to display a message `goodbye!` when the user reaches the limit of inputting wrong password ? If that's so, i have edited the code, try again. I have compiled and executed this code and it runs perfectly according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two Scanner since it would work for userName and Pass word. Do-While works fine here. You keep asking for valid pass word. **Updated with count 3.**

```
package ab;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserLogin{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdIn= new Scanner (System.in);

        String userName; 
        int userPassWord;

        boolean invaildPassWord = false;

        System.out.println("Please enter your name!");
        userName = stdIn.nextLine();    

        System.out.println("Welcome: " + userName);

        do { 
              System.out.println("\nWhat is your password?");
              userPassWord = stdIn.nextInt();

              if (userPassWord ==14567){
                  System.out.println("Password accepted ! you are welcome!");
                  invaildPassWord = false;
              }

              else {
                  System.out.println("Sorry wrong password! Try again");
                  invaildPassWord = true;

        }

        } while(invaildPassWord);
    }   
}
```

Also, you can do it like this. If you don't want "what's your password again and again.

```
package ab;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserLogin{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdIn= new Scanner (System.in);

        String userName; 
        int userPassWord;

        boolean invaildPassWord = false;

        System.out.println("Please enter your name!");
        userName = stdIn.nextLine();    

        System.out.println("Welcome: " + userName);

        System.out.println("\nWhat is your password?");
        userPassWord = stdIn.nextInt();

        do { 
              if (userPassWord ==14567){
                  System.out.println("Password accepted ! you are welcome!");
                  invaildPassWord = false;
              }

              else {
                  System.out.println("Sorry wrong password! Try again");
                  userPassWord = stdIn.nextInt();
                  invaildPassWord = true;

        }

        } while(invaildPassWord);
    }   
}
```

With count 3 times:

```
package ab;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserLogin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userName;
        int userPassWord;
        int count = 3;

        boolean invaildPassWord = false;

        System.out.println("Please enter your name!");
        userName = stdIn.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Welcome: " + userName);

        System.out.println("\nWhat is your password?");
        userPassWord = stdIn.nextInt();

        if (count > 0) {

            do {
                if (userPassWord == 14567) {
                    System.out.println("Password accepted ! you are welcome!");
                    invaildPassWord = false;
                }

                else {
                    --count;
                    System.out.println("Sorry wrong password! Try again");
                    userPassWord = stdIn.nextInt();
                    invaildPassWord = true;

                }

            } while (invaildPassWord && count > 0);

            System.out.println("GoodBye!");
        }
    }
}
```

Without goodbye after valid entry:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserLogin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userName;
        int userPassWord;
        int count = 3;

        boolean invaildPassWord = false;

        System.out.println("Please enter your name!");
        userName = stdIn.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Welcome: " + userName);

        System.out.println("\nWhat is your password?");
        userPassWord = stdIn.nextInt();

        if (count > 0) {

            do {
                if (userPassWord == 14567) {
                    System.out.println("Password accepted ! you are welcome!");
                    invaildPassWord = false;
                }

                else {
                    --count;
                    System.out.println("Sorry wrong password! Try again");
                    userPassWord = stdIn.nextInt();
                    invaildPassWord = true;

                }

            } while (invaildPassWord && count > 0);

            if (count <= 0){
                System.out.println("GoodBye!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you swiss! what i get is Please enter your name!
michel
Welcome: michel

What is your password?
14567
Password accepted ! you are welcome!
GoodBye!
how get i get rid of goodbye since my password is good??? i tried break; but does not work

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
while true{
    Scanner x= new Scanner (System.in);
    int password= x.nextInt();
    if(password ==14567)
    {
        System.out.println("Password accepted ! you are welcome")
        break;

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry wrong password! Try again");
}
```